# "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child" from useState

Tags: react-hooks, e-commerce

I am getting the error "Objects are not valid as a React child" when changing `products` from empty array to an array populated with objects (the `data` in the code below), the error originates at `setProducts(data);`. I cannot understand why because `data` is not an object. I tried to research the answers on the website but couldn't find one matching with my problem. Could someone clarify why I am getting this error?[image]

```
const App = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
        const {data} = await commerce.products.list();
        setProducts(data);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProducts();
    }, []);
    console.log(products);
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Products products={products}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Data might not be an object, but it is a list of objects which is causing the error. Likely in your <Products component you are trying to list your products without putting them in any sort of react element.

You should let us know what the products variable looks like and what is happening in the products component.

Comment: From the keys, it looks like the component is trying to use a Price as if it were an element: https://commercejs.com/docs/api/#types

Answer (score 0):

thank you petermir! i found my mistake: i wrote

```
<Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Grid key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            <Product product={product} onAddToCart={onAddToCart} />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
```

for some reason which i don't know my computer didn't understood it, so i changed it to the following and all the errors disappeared:

```
<Grid container justify='center' spacing={4}>
            {products.map((product)=> { 
                return (
                <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                    <Product product={product}/>
                </Grid>
             )})
             }
</Grid>
```